# How can I correctly serialize and manage colors and sizes for a product with django models?

Tags: python, django-models, serialization, django-rest-framework, e-commerce

I have created `Product`, `Color` and `Size Model`.

`Color` has Foreign Key to `Product` and `Size Model`.

[Django Colors Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uusk6.png)

I designed like this based on recommendations I heard, I'm not sure if this is the best method because I think I have a bunch of duplicated data.

[DrawSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smU0p.png)

How can I achieve this after serializing my models?

**JSON**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Product 1",
        "price": 12.34,
        "images": 5,
        "description": "description of product",
        "category": "category 1",
        "colors": [
            {
                "color": "White",
                "sizes": [
                    {
                        "size": "S",
                        "stock": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "M",
                        "stock": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "L",
                        "stock": 0
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "stock": 10
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "color": "Black",
                "sizes": [
                    {
                        "size": "S",
                        "stock": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "M",
                        "stock": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "L",
                        "stock": 10
                    },
                    {
                        "size": "XL",
                        "stock": 10
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "link": "https://www.example.com/product1"
    }
]
```

I have tried this:

```
class SizeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Size
        fields = ['size', 'stock']


class ColorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sizes = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Color
        fields = ['color', 'sizes']

    def get_sizes(self, obj):
        sizes = Size.objects.filter(id=obj.sizes.id)
        serializer = SizeSerializer(sizes, many=True)
        return serializer.data

class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    colors = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name',
            'price',
            'brand',
            'description',
            'category',
            'colors',
        ]

    def get_colors(self, obj):
        colors = obj.color_set.all()
        serializer = ColorSerializer(colors, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

And I got this:

```
{
    "products": [
        {
            "brand": "Brand",
            "category": "Category 1",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-01T16:54:43.054297-03:00",
            "description": "Description",
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Product 1",
            "numReviews": 0,
            "price": "12.34",
            "rating": null,
            "colors": [
                {
                    "color": "White",
                    "sizes": [
                        {
                            "size": "S",
                            "stock": 10
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "color": "White",
                    "sizes": [
                        {
                            "size": "M",
                            "stock": 10
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "color": "Black",
                    "sizes": [
                        {
                            "size": "S",
                            "stock": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "reviews": [],
            "images": []
        },
        {
            "brand": "Brand",
            "category": "Category 1",
            "createdAt": "2022-12-01T16:58:00.383907-03:00",
            "description": "Description",
            "id": 5,
            "name": "Product 2",
            "numReviews": 0,
            "price": "23.45",
            "rating": null,
            "colors": [
                {
                    "color": "Black",
                    "sizes": [
                        {
                            "size": "S",
                            "stock": 3
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "color": "White",
                    "sizes": [
                        {
                            "size": "M",
                            "stock": 8
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "reviews": [],
            "images": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Looks like it creates an array per size and repeats the color.